# Using embedded jetty with camel-cxf

Tags: apache-camel

I have a couple of rest routes defined in my Camel project and now I'm trying to add a SOAP service to my project using the same jetty embedded server.

I have something like this:

```
restConfiguration()
    .component("jetty")
    .host("0.0.0.0")
    .port(8080)
;

CxfEndpoint cxfEndpoint = new CxfEndpoint();
cxfEndpoint.setCamelContext(getContext());
cxfEndpoint.setServiceClass(TestService.class);
cxfEndpoint.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:8080/test");

from(cxfEndpoint)
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log, "test");
```

When I try to run the application, I get this error message:

> Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Look like it's trying to start 2 instances of Jetty using the same port and that's why it's failing.

I would really like to make the cxf endpoint work with the embedded Jetty used for my other services. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Look like known issue [Port already in use when using CXF consumer and jetty](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Port-already-in-use-when-using-CXF-consumer-and-jetty-td5714378.html)

Comment: You cannot have two processes using the same port. Wont work as they have to listen on that port. Only one can. Change the port number for one. Or implement a process that takes both SOAP and REST and run that on one port.